Close pop-up window opened by .click()
I have a pop-up window which is opened using this code run from console:
// Find all the "Activate" buttons on the page
var offerButtons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("AvailableDealTile2__activation-status___jsguf")).filter(span => span.textContent === "Activate");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < offerButtons.length; ++index) {
    console.log("Clicking Activate button");
    offerButtons[index].click();
    // Wait 2seconds to be nice to WF servers :)
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
}
console.log("All done. Refresh and try again.");

How can I close that popup within that for loop?
I tried the following:
var daddy = window.self;
daddy.opener = window.self;
daddy.close();

but it did not work.

The relevant part appears to be how the "pop window" is opened.

Nothing in this code opens a popup window.

@Barmar apologies if my terminology is off. I'm not a web developer, just looking to do some basic scripting. I suppose the .click() doesn't open a window directly, it clicks on an element on the page that then opens a pop-up window. Perhaps what I need is a way to force close any focused window.

You need to find the code that opens the popup so you can modify it to save the window in a variable. Then you can close that window.

You didn't show the code that actually opens the new window, but you need to assign a variable to that return value (which will be a reference to the new window itself). Then you can close the window by calling .close on that reference.
Here's an example (the snippet below won't work here in SO due to sandboxing, but it will if you try it here):


let newWindow = null;

document.querySelector("#open").addEventListener("click", function(){
  newWindow = window.open("https://example.com");  
});

document.querySelector("#close").addEventListener("click", function(){
  newWindow.close(); 
});
<button id="open" type="button">Open Window</button>
<button id="close" type="button">Close Window</button>




Apologies as I'm not a web developer. Just looking to do some basic scripting. Perhaps my terminology is off. This is the entire script. There is no additional code. The .click() interacts with an existing webpage and does cause a pop-up window to open. My code is not generating the pop-up window, so that's why a .close() will not work, I think.

@Kagey You are triggering the opening of the window, by causing a .click event's callback to fire with offerButtons[index].click(), but whatever that actual callback code is is where a reference to the newly opened window must be created. Without that reference, you won't be able to close the popup (AFAIK).
